# Integrate Pentaho report in spring boot but I face error like The Engine has not been booted and the default keys have no been registered yet

Tags: spring-boot, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have try to **integrate Pentaho report in spring boot** but I face error like

> The Engine has not been booted and the default keys have no been registered yet

How to solve my issue?

After successfully boot load my report view on web page.

Comment: You'll need to give more information about your installation to receive proper help. What steps have you followed to integrate the reports? OS and configuration files modified to achieve the integration...